# Lognormal distribution for Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: excel, simulation, distribution, montecarlo

I have to do this MC Simulation of but the parameters I change should have a lognormal distribution. My problem is that I don't know how to make them have a lognormal distribution. Are the mean and the std deviation found the same way as the normal distribution? Please help me.

Thank you,

Comment: No, they are not the same, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575639/lognormal-distribution/68585321#68585321

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how I can find the mean and standard deviation using the low and high values only please?

Comment: You clearly need mu/sigma for log-normal. What data do you have to compute them?

Comment: I only have the low, base, and high values.

Comment: Could you post them?

Comment: Sure, for example, I have these values for the interest rate:
Low: 4%
Base: 8% 
High: 11.6%

Comment: Mmmm... and how they are related to LN distribution? Anyway, if they are, e.g. related to the LN quantile function, you write several equations for quantile expression (see wiki) and assign it to you low/high/... Then you solve those equation for the mu and sigma, and use those mu and sigma

Comment: Alright I will, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.